# Cannot select the cell but i can set the textLabel

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I just want to select my first cell of my first section, its something simple but it dont want to work...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    // Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;


    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
        {
            NSString *cellIconName = [[self subViewIconNames] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];   
            UIImage *cellIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:cellIconName];
            [[cell imageView] setImage:cellIcon];
            cell.imageView.alpha = 0.5;
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.subViewNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            if ([MyAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].inSubView) {
                    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                    firstIndexPath  =indexPath;
                    cell.selected = YES;
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"yes this changes";
                }
            }



            break;
        }
...
```

So the textlabel changes to "yes this changes" but selected no...

I tried different approaches, also this after the reload:

```
NSIndexPath *ip=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [[MyAppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].rootViewController.tableView  selectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
```

I dont know where to look... please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to do, but may be you should try to use highlighted in addition to selected:

```
cell.selected = YES;
cell.highlighted = YES;
```

Comment: No it's still not selected... very weird

Comment: did you try to use this setter 
[cell setSelected:YES animated:YES]; ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView selectAndScrollToIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newSelectionIndexPath {

    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:newSelectionIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newSelectionIndexPath] setSelected:YES animated:NO];

    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newSelectionIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
}
```